# Using ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize to show or hide views

Tags: zend-framework2

I have recently installed ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize and would like to use them to show or hide various parts of the layout.phtml file.

I understand that BjyAuthorize is a firewall of sorts and the flowchart from git hub suggests it should be possible to get current permission status and to use that to hide or show a particular section of code.

So for instance:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Admin Menu item</li>
    <li>Affiliate menu item</li>
    <li>Guest Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

If an admin user is logged in, he will view all three items, the affiliate will only see Affiliate and guest and the guest will only see guest.

How I was thinking of doing this was something like this:

```php
<?php
    //Get array of permissions for current user *not certain how to do this*
    $permissionArray = $this->GetBjyPermissions($current->user);
?>
<ul>
    <?php if in_array('admin',$permissionArray) {?>
        <li>Admin Menu item</li>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if in_array('affiliate',$permissionArray) {?>
        <li>Affiliate Menu item</li>
    <?php } ?>

    <li>Guest Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Essentially this will allow me to hide the sections of code a user is not allowed to use.

If it is not possible to get the permissions via Bjy or Zfc I guess my option would be to simply query the Database and build a permissions array from that directly.

Has anyone else had to do something like this? Is this approach a good approach or is there another way of achieving this?

Many thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **BjyAuthorize**'s **IsAllowed** view Helper. It knows the current user's identity, so you just have to check the rule. It works like:

```
$isMenuAdmin = $this->isAllowed( 'menu', 'menu_admin' );
$isMenuAffiliate = $this->isAllowed( 'menu', 'menu_affiliate' );
$isMenuGuest = $this->isAllowed( 'menu', 'menu_guest' );
```

***menu*** is a resource and ***menu_**** a rule. You have to define them in the **bjyauthorize.global.php**. I'd do it this way:

```
(...)
'resource_providers' => array(
    'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
        'menu' => array(),
    ),
),
'rule_providers' => array(
    'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config' => array(
        'allow' => array(
            /*
            [0] -> role
            [1] -> resource
            [2] -> rule
            */
            array( array( 'admin' ), 'menu', array( 'menu_admin' ) ),
            array( array( 'affiliate' ), 'menu', array( 'menu_affiliate' ) ),
            array( array( 'guest' ), 'menu', array( 'menu_guest' ) ),
        ),
    ),
),
(...)
```

BTW, it seems that you're trying to build a menu. I recommend you to [check this post](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/integrating-bjyauthorize-with-zendnavigation/) about integrating Zend Navigation with BjyAutorize.

Comment: Thank you, this really made it clear as to how to use the helper. Many thanks!